# How can I select <span> inside <h1>

Tags: html, nested

I need to target the content of the span but not nested h1 content
Does anyone has an idea of how is that possible?
-down is a simple example:
Thanks

```
<html> 
   <div> 
      <h1>MainTitle <span>SubTitle </span> </h1> 
   </div> 
</html>
```

Comment: from what language are you trying to select it from? JavaScript?

Comment: <html>
<div>
  <h1>MainTitle

    <span>SubTitle </span>

  </h1>

</div>

</html>

Comment: select using javascript or css?

Comment: .... are you by chance trying to make a webpage with HTML alone?

Comment: @Tyler thank you for the answer it was for typescript based testing.. but solved by now ... sorry being too late to thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select with CSS, use `h1 span {}` like this:

```css
h1 span {
 color: blue;
 font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html> 
   <div> 
      <h1>MainTitle <span>SubTitle </span> </h1> 
   </div> 
</html>
```

With javascript, I guess you have to add an ID to your span tag. I don't know any other way of doing it. Here is the code to show:

```js
document.getElementById("h1span").style.color = "blue";
document.getElementById("h1span").style.fontSize = "20px";
```

```html
<html> 
   <div> 
      <h1>MainTitle <span id="h1span">SubTitle </span> </h1> 
   </div> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.. the thing is i can't manipulate with the original code here. but it may work like this or be targeting the element by its content!